# Launching an iphone app from custom URL in sms

Tags: iphone, url, sms

I have a problem with launching my app from an url in an sms.

When I open my Safari and type "myapp://" it opens my application, but somehow the iPhone sms parser can't recognize my url in the body of the message.

I tried:

```
myapp://something

myapp:something

<myapp://something>
```

and still the URL in sms message is not clickable.

I have configured the URL identifier and scheme (because it works through safari).

Comment: This sounds like a deficiency in the iPhone's SMS app that you can't do anything about (except ask Apple to implement this feature).

Comment: I removed the scheme tag. Please only tag questions with scheme if they are about the programming language scheme.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (not a good one) would be to send the user to Safari with a original http:// address and redirect the user to my app-url. This only requires simple HTML-Knowledge (and a webhost).

`http://myapp.info/?id=myuniqueidfortheuser`

The downside with this is that you must go through Safari to open the app.

This is the only solution I can think of with these restrictions by Apple.
I really hope they can fix this in the future.

Best of luck to you and I hope you'll solve this problem.