# How can i launch myApp from sms?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, android-mapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launching application from a SMS message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625232/launching-application-from-a-sms-message)
>   [launch an app from a link in an sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512664/launch-an-app-from-a-link-in-an-sms)

Suppose I want to open myApp  from sms. How can I open it from sms and also  want to provide the data from sms to myApp.

Comment: A bit too vague.  Are your trying to force the SMS app to open your app, or send SMS inside your app?

Comment: [This has been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946045/need-to-open-the-application-when-sms-arrives-and-spell-the-arrived-sms-in-iphon) [a few times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512664/launch-an-app-from-a-link-in-an-sms) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228386/launching-an-iphone-app-from-custom-url-in-sms).

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to open your app when the user receives a sms or to open the sms app from within your app?

Comment: Suppose i send one string in my sms. Then I want to open myApp from that sms.I have registered the url scheme but i dont understand that how can i used the string coming in sms to print in label in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a URL scheme, try and follow this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

And be kind and register your [handleOpenURL](http://www.handleOpenURL.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. You can only open other apps if the app doing the opening is aware of a custom URL scheme supported by the app being opened. You obviously can't customize the Messages app to this end.